# SQLite indexing JSON properties for LIKE queries with `->>` operator

Tags: json, sqlite, indexing

I have the following table in SQLite 3.41.2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE node (
    id         TEXT NOT NULL,
    label      TEXT NOT NULL,
    properties TEXT NOT NULL, -- containing JSON
    PRIMARY KEY (
        id
    )
);
```

I noticed that some queries accessing subfields of `properties` were performing slow. So I added an index for the `$.string` property:

```sql
CREATE INDEX node_properties_string_nocase ON node (properties ->> '$.string' COLLATE NOCASE);
```

But `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` for a specific query reveals that SQLite seems to disregard the index:

```sql
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM node WHERE label = 'x' AND properties ->> '$.string' LIKE 'y%';
--> SCAN node
```

To solve this, I rewrote my queries and indexes to use `JSON_EXTRACT(...)` instead of `->>`, and SQLite happily uses the indexes. But it left me with the question: is it true that SQLite does not support indexes with the `->>` operator, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to read and understand the subtle difference between the two (*`->>` (and also `->`) and `json_extract(...)`*) as per

- https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_and_operators

which includes:-

> **Thus, these operators are subtly different from a two-argument json_extract()**

Comment: Thanks, I read that article. So `->>` always returns an SQL representation of the subcomponent, while `JSON_EXTRACT(...)` returns either the SQL representation (if the second argument references a JSON null, string or numeric value) or a JSON value.
In my case, the `string` property of the JSON always contains either a string or `null`, so there should be no difference between the two operators, correct?

Comment: @RaphaelMüller that is from the result aspect. Whether or not an index is used or not is not based upon the result. For an expression index it is based upon an exact match of the expression. (see https://sqlite.org/expridx.html). You could, even though it is frowned upon, use the `INDEXED BY` clause (see https://sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html).